How to change float values smoothly using coroutine?
inside OnValidate
private void OnValidate()
{
    // Handle changes to changeBothRadius
    if (changeBothRadius != previousBothRadius)
    {
        SyncRadii(); // Sync radii when changeBothRadius changes
        previousBothRadius = changeBothRadius;
    }
    else if (xradius != previousXradius || yradius != previousYradius)
    {
        // Allow independent changes to xradius and yradius
        Debug.Log($"Updating radii: X = {xradius}, Y = {yradius}");
        previousXradius = xradius;
        previousYradius = yradius;
    }

    // Update LineRenderer and object positions
    if (line != null && draw)
    {
        ConfigureLineRenderer();
        CreatePoints();
        AdjustPositions(numOfObjects, transform.position, xradius, yradius); // Pass both radii
    }
}

when i call this method SyncRadii it's changing both xradius and yradius values at once like "jumping" the values to be the same value of the changeBothRadius.
for example if i xradius 3 and yradius is 7 and i change changeBothRadius value to 10 then both xradius and yradius "jump" to the value 10.
instead i want them to change the values smoothly.
void SyncRadii()
{
    xradius = changeBothRadius;
    yradius = changeBothRadius;

    previousXradius = xradius;
    previousYradius = yradius;
}

what i tried to do in this method is:
void SyncRadii()
{
    // Start the coroutine to smooth the radius change
    StopAllCoroutines(); // Stop any ongoing radius adjustments
    StartCoroutine(SmoothSyncRadii(changeBothRadius, 0.5f)); // Adjust over 0.5 seconds

    previousXradius = xradius;
    previousYradius = yradius;
}

and added this coroutine:
private IEnumerator SmoothSyncRadii(float targetRadius, float duration)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    float startXRadius = xradius;
    float startYRadius = yradius;

    while (elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        float t = elapsedTime / duration;

        // Smoothly interpolate the radii
        xradius = Mathf.Lerp(startXRadius, targetRadius, t);
        yradius = Mathf.Lerp(startYRadius, targetRadius, t);

        yield return null; // Wait until the next frame
    }

    // Ensure the final value is set
    xradius = targetRadius;
    yradius = targetRadius;
}

but still when i change the changeBothRadius value the xradius and yradius "jump" to the changeBothRadius value and noy changing smoothly to that value.

I'd say, consider using async/await functions, they'll be called in the background thread like co-routines do, and IMO they're easier to wrap your head around. Just be careful, an unhandled exception in async void function (not Task ) will result in the whole application immediate crash.

Without using EditorCoroutine this will anyway only work during play mode ... No idea how it would be handled using ExecuteAlways but afaik in that case the update call might be called more often for various events resulting in the routine finishing too fast

So, you have different approaches here that could work.
I believe it's important to understand what these approaches are designed for before making your choice.
OnValidate [bad choice] 
It is triggered sporadically when serialized properties are changed or scripts recompile but it doesn't run consistently, making it unsuitable for smooth, frame-dependent operations. This is great to validate user data in the inspector!
OnDrawGizmos [Recommended for quick prototyping, with limitations] 
Perfect for frame-dependent updates while the Scene view is active. On the other hand... it stops when the Scene view is not rendering, coupling the behavior with the editor's rendering process.
This works great when you want to render operations your scripts are doing (raycasting, positioning, distances, trigger areas, ...).
So... on a practical level it could perfectly satisfy your needs but it's not a great choice for a long-term solution right?
Please check OnDrawGizmosSelected too.
ExecuteAlways [not the cleanest choice] 
This is great for cases where a behavior designed for running constantly during play could/should also run while not playing. Let's say you're setting up a scene to render a Model rotating on the Y axis in loop: it could be useful to see the model rotating even when not playing, maybe while finishing up with the rest of the environment. --> ExecuteAlways
EditorCoroutines [Recommended for long term solutions] 
Provides clean, consistent frame updates independent of Scene view rendering. Requires the Editor Coroutines package and to understand that some yield won't work as in standard Coroutines (WaitForSecRealTime) but... since you were using OnValidate [editor only callback method] and tried coroutines, I assume EditorCoroutines are perfect for your case.
Oh, you need to download a pkg I believe.
AsyncMethods [ great alternative ] 
Per editor frame using async/await... needs a little effort to get used to it if you never had but it could provide a great solution without having to download extra pkgs or forcing "dirty approaches".
This approach is very versatile and it isn't really limited to very specific scenarios.
